# How to implement generic for a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need to implement something like this

```
1. type ABC<X> = (x: X) => X
2. 
3. const abc: ABC = (x: X) => {
4.   return x;
5. }; 
6. 
7. const q: number = abc<number>(123);
```

but there are error in the line #3 - *Generic type 'ABC' requires 1 type argument(s).*

when I try to make something like

```
3. const abc: ABC<X> = (x: X) => {
4.   return x;
5. };
```

it shows new error - *Cannot find name 'X'.*. But I don't have type definition on that stage.

for sure I could make something like this

```
3. function abc<X>(x: X) {
4.   return x;
5. };
```

and remove type ABC at all

**but the idea to have it**. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Is this a homework problem or something?  I'm wondering what your actual use case is.  It's not possible to implement `ABC` because `ABC` is not a type... it's a type function.  To get a type you need to specify `ABC`'s type parameter.  You can implement, say, `ABC<string>` or `ABC<number>` or `ABC<XYZ>` where `XYZ` is a type.  Or, you can redefine `ABC` to be a type like `type ABC = <X>(x: X) => X` and implement that, but since I don't understand your use case I don't know which way to advise.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz thanks for your reply. yes, it's kind of homework. here is a code from real tasks, so you can see the use case - https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-breeze-lsl7e?file=/index.ts

task: function loses its arguments typing, because of "any" usage. All "any" should be replaced with something.

so I tried to solve it via generics, but I am stuck.

Comment: So, that's a different question. This looks like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where X (your actual problem) is "how can I give a better type definition to `Trottle` so that it doesn't lose the typing of its arguments", and Y (what you asked about) is "how can I implement `ABC` where `ABC` is not something implementable."  If you could edit this question so it's about `Trottle` or something directly analogous to your question, I (or someone else maybe) would be happy to give you an answer.  The solution for `Trottle` does involve generics, but not like `ABC`.

Comment: @jcalz thanks. seems the solution is using `type ABC = <X>(x: X) => X` as you mentioned in your first comment. It's my first experience with generic types, and looks like I confused it with Alias Types.